# Sqlite datatype

Tags: java, sqlite

I am using sqlite and java as programming language. I have a class which is

```
public class DataSet {

    public ArrayList<Double> a = null;
    public ArrayList<Double> b = null;
    public ArrayList<Double> c = null;

    public DataSet() {
        a = new ArrayList<Double>();
        b = new ArrayList<Double>();
        c = new ArrayList<Double>();
    }
}
```

I want to store `DATA`, where `DataSet DATA=new DataSet();` in sqlite. But I am looking to do it **once**( **not** in a for loop to get data one by one). Is there any dataset which I can use that and store the whole thing like an image in a C#?

Comment: DATA is an object from class DataSet. DataSet DATA=new DataSet();

Comment: What's wrong with doing it in a loop? Why do you need to write it 'all at once'? Are you trying to get the benefits of a SQLite transaction?

Comment: No time is important for me I have so many data and takes a lot to store in db!I have a lot of more function which use DataSet!

Comment: Ok. So, are you trying to write an entire `ArrayList` at once, or ALL the data in the entire `DATA` object at once? Also, how much total data are we talking about here? Can you give us a sample of how much data you're trying to write to the database, or the total number of write operations you're doing?

Comment: each of these arrays are about 1000 elements..so it would be about 3000 times writing in database!

Comment: what you need is a binary blob in the database and this api - http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html - but i need to go out for dinner so hopefully someone else will give more details.  @normal - from the "image" reference i think this idea is to store the byte array (there are C# examples converting images, doing this).

Comment: Yeah Andrew you know what I mean I will try that:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to store the object like an Image? So as a whole... Make the object Serializable like this:

```
public class DataSet implements Serializable {
  /* this is the version of this class,
     increment, when you change the implementation */
  public static final serialVersionUID  = 1L;
  ...
}
```

And store the binary result into a byte array with an `ObjectOutputStream`. This byte array you can save into your database as a BLOB. For example if your table has an id and a data column:

```
byte[] data;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
try {
  oos.writeObject(DATA);
  data = bos.toByteArray();
} finally {
  oos.close();
}    

PreparedStatement pstmt = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(
    "insert into MYTABLE (id, data) values (?, ?)");
pstmt.setLong(1);
pstmt.setBlob(2, new ByteArrayInputStream(data));

...
```

Commit the data, close the connection. Warning: This code is not tested...

Reading the blob from the database again you can use an `ObjectInputStream` on the byte array you get from the BLOB just as above only the other way around. I leave that for you to code.

Please remember that storing data in a serialized way it will not be human-readable, so you can not open your SQLite, look into it and find out if your data is reasonable.

Good luck!